# Why isn't this simple javascript working?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

This javascript all but works with exception of radiobuttonlist.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function validate() {
    if (document.getElementById("<%=txtballotName.ClientID%>").value == "") {
        alert("Ballot Name can not be blank");
        document.getElementById("<%=txtballotName.ClientID%>").focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (document.getElementById("<%=txtballotCity.ClientID %>").value == "") {
        alert("Ballot City can not be blank");
        document.getElementById("<%=txtballotCity.ClientID %>").focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("<%=txtballotState.ClientID%>").value == "") {
        alert("Ballot State cannot be blank");
        document.getElementById("<%=txtballotState.ClientID%>").focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("<%=txtballotZip.ClientID%>").value == "") {
        alert("Zip Code cannot be blank");
        document.getElementById("<%=txtballotZip.ClientID%>").focus();
        return false;
    }
        if (document.getElementById("<%= txtreceivedby.ClientID %>").checked == false) {
        alert("Request Received By can not be blank");
        document.getElementById("<%=txtreceivedby.ClientID%>").focus();
        return false;
    }

     return true;
}
```

The radiobuttonList looks like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <label for="txtreceivedby_0">FAX</label>
        <input id="txtreceivedby_0" type="radio" name="txtreceivedby" value="Fax" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <label for="txtreceivedby_1">EMAIL</label>
        <input id="txtreceivedby_1" type="radio" name="txtreceivedby" value="Mail" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <label for="txtreceivedby_2">PHONE</label>
        <input id="txtreceivedby_2" type="radio" name="txtreceivedby" value="Phone" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

So far, the other form field are validating except the txtreceivedby radio button. I am not getting any errors but it isn't validating either.
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you 5x more people to be able to help you, you would NOT post your ASP stuff, but would post the actual HTML that the browser sees which you can capture with View/Source in the browser.  Lots of people read HTML, not so many read ASP.

Comment: SIR, I selected asp and javascript tags so that generous and kind people in those spaces can help if they wish to.

Comment: His point is that many more people know javascript than know both javascript and asp.net.  If you post the html and javascript which is the result of your .net code rather than the .net code, people who don't know asp.net can help you as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP's radiobuttonlist render as a table containing radio button items. Therefore, it is a bit complicated  to get the checked status of radio button.

You might find various sources if you google for "ASP radiobuttonlist and javascript". I have tested some of them and not every of them worked well specially if your page created from Master page.

However, I have tried in my own way and here it is:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="txtReceivedBy" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Fax" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Email" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Phon" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
<input type="button" onclick="alert(checkedRadio());" value="Test RadioButtonChecked Status" />
```

and the javascript I have used to get the cehcked status is here

```
function checkedRadio() {
    var rtn = false;
    var i = 0;
    var radioBoxesContainer = document.getElementById("<%=txtReceivedBy.ClientID%>");
    if (radioBoxesContainer) {
        var radioBoxes = radioBoxesContainer.getElementsByTagName("input");
        if (radioBoxes && radioBoxes.length > 0) {
            for (i - 0; i < radioBoxes.length; i++) {
                if (radioBoxes[i].checked) {
                    rtn = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return rtn;
}
```

if you are interested to get a live demo,
you can find it here http://plugins.amiwithyou.com/sof/

Answer (score 1):

You can create a short little utility function that will get you the value of any radio group:

```
function getRadioValue(name) {
    var items = document.getElementsByName(name);
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i].checked) {
            return(items[i].value);
        }
    }
}
```

You can then get the checked item in your radio group like this:

```
var val = getRadioValue("txtreceivedby");
```

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/PHXaC/

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell major headache; if you'd page me, I'd go with a nice good ol' fashion `<select>` box.

But to be useful, you need to have a look with view source at exactly what the ASP code plasts out to the browser. I don't know ASP but I bet it's either outputting 3 different ids on each radio, or the same id (#txtreceivedby) on all three of them.

Whatever it gives out, the validation code `if(bla_bla_blah.checked===false)` is wrong because it only targets just one in the set of radios and even with that fixed, that radio might not return `.checked===false` cross-browser.

Comment: sorry SIRs. I was looking at it differently, perhaps wrongly. I was thinking you guys would be more interested in showing me how to use javascript to code radiobuttonlist in asp.net. Sorry for the wrong assumption. I have updated the code with actual HTML of that radiobutton.